# instruments pipe stdout to console

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments

I'm looking to automate our iPhone unit tests by executing our unit test code directly on the device using the 'instruments' CLI (documentation linked below).

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html

The application runs which is fine.  However, I can't figure out a way to have it dump the stdout to a file or pipe the stdout to the console?